# passing data from reacttable to react modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-table

Having a hard time in fetching data from a selected row in our apps react-table component and displaying data in a Modal. I've attempted to fetch data with this.state.data.Issue and alerted it, but it returns undefined every time I click the button in a specific row inside our table. Is there a way to solve my problem? Because this modal will serve as the form where the admin can see the Issue details and approve or stall a reported issue.

here's my code:

```
class Sumbong extends Component {


    handleButtonClick = (e, row) => {
        this.setState({ visible: true});
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: [],
            createAt: '',
            data: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        refs.on('value', snap => {
            let requests = [];
            snap.forEach(reqs => {

                let ID = reqs.key
                let reqObject = reqs.val();
                const {name, Issue, createAt, LocStamp, Status} = reqs.val();
                requests.push({ID, name, Issue, createAt, LocStamp, Status});
            })
            this.setState({data: requests})
            console.log('requests: ', requests);

        })
    }

 render() {

        const columns = [
            {
                Header: "uid",
                accessor: "ID",
                show: false
            },
            {
                Header: "Sender's Name",
                accessor: "name",
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px'
                },
            },
            {
                Header: "Report Category",
                accessor: "Issue",
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px'
                },
            },
            {
                Header: "Date Reported",
                accessor: "createAt",
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px'
                },
            },
            {
                Header: "Location",
                accessor: "LocStamp",
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px'
                },
            },
            {
                Header: "Status",
                accessor: "Status",
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px'
                },
            },
            {
                Header: "Actions",
                accessor: "ID",
                filterable: false,
                Cell: ({ row }) => (
                    <div style={buttonTablestyle}>
                        <Button bsStyle="warning" onClick={e => this.handleButtonClick(e, row)}>Edit</Button>



                    </div>
                )
            },

        ]

        return (
            <div className="container">

                {this.state.visible && <Modal
                    title="title"
                    visible={this.state.visible}
                    onClickAway={() => this.closeModal()}
                >

                    <section>
                       {/*<p> {this.state.createdAt}dsds</p>*/}
                        {alert("Output: "+this.state.data.Issue)}
                    </section>

                </Modal>}

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
                      id="bootstrap-css"></link>
                <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
                        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
                        crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
                        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
                        crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
                        crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
                {/*<---CSS & Bootstrap Scripts/Links*/}

                    <h2 className="h2_style">Sumbong Center</h2>


                {/*<div className="searchBar">*/}
                    {/*<input type="text" style={SearchBox_Sumbong} className="CircularInput" id="DocsSearchBar"*/}
                           {/*placeholder="Search applicant's name..."/>*/}
                {/*</div>*/}

                <ReactTable
                    style={tableFont}
                    filterable={true}
                    defaultFilterMethod={filterCaseInsensitive}
                    columns={columns}
                    defaultPageSize={5}
                    className="-striped -highlight"
                    data={this.state.data}
                >



                </ReactTable>


            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Sumbong;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the components which need to share state data aren't closely linked by parent-child relationships (which would make passing the data through props difficult), you may want to consider moving the relevant state into a state management library like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or using the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in newer versions of React.